# How to build and embed the output of a Message entity created by the Message module?

Tags: 7, entities, message-subscribe

I need to, given the `mid` (= Message ID), generate the Message content for a specific view mode. How can I do this?

It seems to be complicated by the fact that a Message is an entity (created by the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module), and there are multiple Message types, each of which have their own fields and rely heavily on tokens.

I'm hoping for something simple like:

```
$message = message_load($mid, $view_mode);
$output = drupal_render(entity_view($message));
```

... but everything I've found that loads Messages seems to rely on weird wrappers and stuff and I haven't been able to find a working solution no matter how much I tinker with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a better one:

```
$build = $message->buildContent('my_view_mode');
$output = drupal_render($build);
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
$message = message_load($mid);
$build = $message->view();
$build += array(
  '#theme' => 'message',
  '#entity' => $message,
  '#view_mode' => 'full',
);  
$output = drupal_render($build);
```

Comment: not sure where you found the view() method, this is probably from Entity itself? Message class has a own method for that.